# SQL subquery on how to distinguished what has been ordered

Tags: sql, subquery

I need to list all the books for which at least 4 copies have been ordered from the bookstore and the copies may come from multiple orders. I am not understanding how to get the copies when I don't see an field close to that.

Here is a pic of the tables and fields I'm working with.
[image: tables and fields of database]

Comment: you really should post your attempted workings and not ask people to do your homework

Comment: You can use the COUNT function: 
SELECT [BOOK_ID] FROM [YOUR_TABLE] GROUP BY [BOOK_ID] HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select t2.Title,t3.Qty
    from Books t2
    JOIN (
    Select t1.ISBN,t1.SUM(Quantity) as Qty
    from OrderLines t1
    Group by t1.ISBN) t3
    ON t2.ISBN=t3.ISBN
    Where t3.Qty >= 4
```

Comment: An item does not appear in an Order/OrderLine unles it has been sold. So we're using `SUM()` _quantity_ to work out how many have been sold. And then joining on _ISBNs_ to get the relevant book _title_. The `Where` clause limits the results to where 4 or more items have been sold.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...just one question im not familiar with one of your lines.  The line that is: ON t2.ISBN=t3.ISBN can you explain that to me?

Comment: For this kind of join (an `INNER JOIN`) 'JOIN ON' will work the same as `JOIN Where` you may be more familiar with seeing
eg1. `FROM t2 JOIN t3 Where t2.ISBN=t3.ISBN` than eg2. `FROM t2 JOIN t3 ON t2.ISBN=t3.ISBN`
It's easier to quickly read SQL when you know all the table joins are beside `ON` and joins can suffer in performance when using `JOIN WHEN`. 
The opposite is also true, People sometimes put conditions in an `ON` clause (and it behaves like a `where`) but there are performance  issues. 
It's good practice to keep Joins in `ON` and conditions in `Where` clauses